# Missing close reasons - can we add more?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Often I find a question that clearly is not OK, and have to choose inappropriate close reason, simply because the right reason is missing.

Reasons I often need:

- **Not a question** - it is a statement, like "I want to do this". There may be error somewhere, but it is not described in the question.
- **Lack of minimal understanding** - the author asks about a problem and has no clue what he really wants or is doing. This kind of question is typically accompanied by a random piece of WordPress code.
- **Zero research effort** - the question can be solved in 5 seconds by typing it into Google, but the author simply didn't bother.
- **Gimme teh codez** - typically a homework / assignment. Author expects someone to solve it and post as answer. Closely related to *Not a question*.

Then there's also problem with migrating - I often need to suggest migration to eg. unix, but it is not in the list.

Comment: We used to have some of these reasons, but they were a source of unending confusion and often impoliteness.  We had "Not a real question", and we had "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding". Both were misapplied all the time, and the latter was used spitefully. We also had "Too Localized", which was used as a catch-all for any question people couldn't be bothered to research a proper duplicate or help the OP with.

Comment: re `"thanks for supportive downvote"` -- Don't get worried or upset about down votes here in meta. It has nothing to do with being "supportive" or not and all to do with whether the voter agrees with your premise. Regarding that, "not a question" is already covered by "Too Broad", "Lack of..." is a bit insulting as none of us is born with programming knowledge and all start out ignorant. I do agree with "zero research effort" and with "Gimme the code" and wished that I had a Mjölnir for those.

Comment: These are all covered well with what we already have at hand. I don't see any need for additional close reasons as you have proposed. If you think you need to clarify for the OP, leave an appropriate omment.

Comment: Downvotes address both "Gimme teh codez" and "Zero research effort" quite handily.  In fact, research effort _is advertised_ as the reason for upvotes when you mouse over it.

Comment: Then perhaps the description for Too broad could be made more apparent? From what it says now, I don't think this would fall under it. For "Lack of", it's simply that you can't help such user. They don't know what they're doing, so don't know what to show in the question, and when you give good answer, they just ask about what you meant. It's utter waste of time.

Comment: @PaulCrovella if we had that option, I'd use it all the time xD

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I remember those were available, and was really surprised that they were removed. They were most fitting in a lot of cases, now people flag it as "Can not reproduce" or "Unclear" simply because there's no good fit.

Comment: @MightyPork Somewhere in http://meta.stackexchange.com (formerly meta.SO) the changes for these reasons and lengthy ensuing discussions all lie. The "minimal understanding" reason was quite nasty. Truckloads of questions were closed with it each day, on novice programmers. Replacing it with "Why doesn't this code work?" was a very good thing IMO.

Comment: One idea I liked which was never implemented was a "General Reference" reason (basically RTFM) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason

Comment: whoa "primarily opinion based"? Isn't that kind of the NATURE of discussion questions on Meta?

Answer (score 4):

Existing close reasons cover all of these cases.

> Not a question - it is a statement, like "I want to do this". There may be error somewhere, but it is not described in the question.

Unclear what you're asking.

> Lack of minimal understanding - the author asks about a problem and has no clue what he really wants or is doing. This kind of question is typically accompanied by a random piece of WordPress code.

OT -> "What is wrong with this code?"

> Zero research effort - the question can be solved in 5 seconds by typing it into Google, but the author simply didn't bother.

OT -> "What is wrong with this code?"

> Gimme teh codez - typically a homework / assignment. Author expects someone to solve it and post as answer. Closely related to Not a question.

Too broad.

Comment: Do they? Then it looks like the close reasons and their descriptions aren't very well written.

Comment: The close reasons are designed to be broad and cover a wide variety of cases. And, if you feel that none do well enough, you can always fill in a custom reason.

Answer (score -3):

You missed 'OP doesn't have the debugging skills to progress beyond 'Hello World'.